# Real-time map generate on web like a Rviz

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic, realtime, rosbridge, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there
By the time I came to this question, I got a lot of great information on the internet, but the combination of 'rosbridge' and 'robot web tool' or 'ros2djs' is just displaying the generated map The I want to see the process of gmapping generating a map like rviz in real time on the web. Please let me know the solution for that. Please excuse my poor English.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319626/real-time-map-generate-on-web-like-a-rviz/) by [justinROScolleage](https://answers.ros.org/users/40627/justinroscolleage/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-03-26**:
rviz is just subscribing to the `/map` topic and displaying it as gmapping generates updates. I haven't used the various ROS web tools that you mentioned, but you should be able to have them subscribe to the `/map` topic and display updates in real time too.

**Comment by [justinROScolleage](https://answers.ros.org/users/40627/justinroscolleage/) on 2019-03-26**:
thank you for your comment!
Yes, I just wanna subscribe to the /map and display that on the web!
But I cannot find the way to this.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-03-26**:
I don't know much about javascript or the ROS web tools, but some quick browsing of the documentation brought me to http://robotwebtools.org/jsdoc/ros2djs/current/maps_OccupancyGridClient.js.html , which seems to be able to subscribe to an occupancy grid and display it. I wasn't able to find a working example of that in a quick search, but there have been a lot of talks and documentation about the robot web tools packages, so I suspect that if you look hard enough, you'll be able to find something.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-03-26**:
Looks like I was a bit slow; @billy's comment includes a working example of the class that I linked to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the answer to this question:
https://answers.ros.org/question/315015/what-is-the-best-way-to-monitor-and-remote-control-the-robot-from-tablet/#315022

I put working code up that displays the map in webbrowser locally or remotely.

Of course all that code started as samples from robotwebtools.org and ROS tutorials - but I admit I have not tried it while gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2019-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [justinROScolleage](https://answers.ros.org/users/40627/justinroscolleage/) on 2019-03-27**:
Thank you for @ahendrix @billy!
I examined how to combine ROS and javascript to make a system, but I could not find a detailed tutorial.
Please tell me the information you referenced when creating your own program.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-03-27**:
So you had me curious. **Now I have tried it with gmapping and it works**.But you need to tweek the code I linked to in earlier comment to continuously update the map.  Add ", continuous : true" to the gridClient

```
var gridClient = new ROS2D.OccupancyGridClient({
  ros : ros,
  rootObject : viewer.scene,
  continuous : true
});
```

The map updates every 15 - 30 seconds on my old laptop running everything..

**Comment by [justinROScolleage](https://answers.ros.org/users/40627/justinroscolleage/) on 2019-03-27**:
This is all I was looking for!
I can’t thank you enough:)
you and @ahendrix made me notice OccupancyGrid.
Thank you and so so much.

**Comment by [Addy_thegreat](https://answers.ros.org/users/54915/addy_thegreat/) on 2020-05-20**:
Thanks @billy for your work!

**Comment by [Addy_thegreat](https://answers.ros.org/users/54915/addy_thegreat/) on 2020-05-20**:
I am using your html code give in the link https://answers.ros.org/question/315015/what-is-the-best-way-to-monitor-and-remote-control-the-robot-from-tablet/#315022  for gmapping of turtlebot3_world.The page is displaying the generation process of the map but it is not showing robot's position on that map.....
Looks like the roslibjs is not able to subscribe /robot_pose .....
On the console I see 'Before callback' and 'creating robotMarkr: ' but I didn't saw 'In pose subscribe callback','Got Pose data:' and 'Pose updated: ' ........please resolve my problem @billy @ahendrix @justinROScolleage

**Comment by [saintdere](https://answers.ros.org/users/53008/saintdere/) on 2020-06-12**:
What commands are needed to display the robot's position on the map? When I run the page, the square where the map should be is empty @Addy_thegreat

**Comment by [Addy_thegreat](https://answers.ros.org/users/54915/addy_thegreat/) on 2020-06-12**:
Clone rosbridge_suite and mjpeg_server from github at first @saintdere

**Comment by [saintdere](https://answers.ros.org/users/53008/saintdere/) on 2020-06-16**:
I have cloned those, but what are the commands you run in terminal?

**Comment by [Addy_thegreat](https://answers.ros.org/users/54915/addy_thegreat/) on 2020-06-16**:
If you have installed it right enter this command in terminal

roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch

and on new terminal run

rosrun mjpeg_server mjpeg_server

..............................

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite/Tutorials/RunningRosbridge
You visit this link to learn more about it  @saintdere

**Comment by [saintdere](https://answers.ros.org/users/53008/saintdere/) on 2020-06-18**:
The mjpeg_server is from [this](http://wiki.ros.org/mjpeg_server#mjpeg_server.2Fgroovy.CA-c5d6c0490d1b3bd11b1b3a26b4d160c211b333ca_4) but isn't it deprecated? And you use this for turtlebot3 in gazebo right? So you run those commands along with the turtlebot3_world command?

**Comment by [Arun_kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/65790/arun_kumar/) on 2021-04-02**:
@billy I have tried the way told in this thread
but at the webpage the map is offset at the left-bottom corner inside the Scence Viewer.
How should view the map in full size??

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2021-04-03**:
@Arun_kumar...I have a confession. I'm not a web programmer. It is set to the left side of my browser as well and I never saw a need to change it. I suggest you research HTML or CSS page formatting and put the grid client in a box in the middle of the page.